# Как сделать кнопку из 3 точек в android?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать в правом верхнем углу кнопку из 3 точек, при нажатии на которую вылезет кнопка "справка", а эта кнопка в свою очередь выведет диалоговое окно справки.

Сейчас в моём приложении тема "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar", и по умолчанию такой кнопки нет.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/light"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/light"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:icon="@mipmap/light"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#e5a840</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#c47505</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#440000</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно создать ресурс menu (`res->menu` ПКМ `New-> Menu resource file`), например spravka.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/popup_spravka"
        android:title="Справка"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Далее в активити переопределить методы:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.spravka, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.popup_spravka:
            myPopup_spravka();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Вместо `myPopup_spravka()`нужно указать свой метод.